# Passing a variable into User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, devexpress

I want to pass one of the textbox's(on the master page) value into the user control(.ascx) page. Here is my code shows how to open user control..

```
Control usrCnt= LoadControl("userControl.ascx");
usrCnt.ID = "usrCnt";
ASPxPanel1.Visible = true;
ASPxPanel1.Controls.Clear();
ASPxPanel1.Controls.Add(userCnt);
```

How can post the textbox's value to the user control? I can't do like this..

```
Control usrCnt= LoadControl("userControl.ascx?param=" + textbox.Text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method for your usercontrol like SetText
and then

```
 usrCnt.SetText("textValue");
```

if it is your webusercontrol code behind

```
   public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void SetText(string theText)
        {
            this.Label1.Text = theText;
        }
    }
```

and if you've been added the control to the page
in page  call it as

```
 this.WebUserControl11.SetText(TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: _An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property_

i have this error.

Comment: did you add the user control to the webpage?!

Answer (score 1):

put these on the upper part of your usercontrol

```
private string _TextBoxValue = string.Empty;
public string TextBoxValue {
    get { return _TextBoxValue; }
    set { _TextBoxValue = value; }
}
```

then on your masterpage

```
usrCnt.TextBoxValue = TextBox1.Text;
```

For the quickest and dirty way is on your MasterPage

> ViewState["TextBoxValue"] = TextBox1.Text();

and on UserControl, access `ViewState["TextBoxValue"]` to get the value.